# How to Clip a dynamic image?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, wpf-controls

I am facing a problem while clipping an Image in C# (wpf/silverlight). I am doing like this with an Image of 640x960 resolution:

```
<Image Source="/someImage.png">
<Image.Clip>
        <EllipseGeometry Center="320,480" RadiusX="120" RadiusY="120" />
    </Image.Clip>
</Image>
```

But above code not even clipping image properly. Any Idea ?

My second concern is, If the parameters of Image coming through some web API (eg. Height and width of image). Then how to bind/calculate Center and Radius.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1) You don't see you image content because you didn't specify `Width` and `Height` properties(by default their values are set to `0`).
2)To bind `Center`, `RadiusX`, `RadiusY` properties you should create view model(you should be familiar with MVVM pattern) and then set it to your image `DataContext` property:

```
public class ImageViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Point _center;
    private int _radiusX;
    private int _radiusY;


    public Point Center
    {
        get
        {
            return _center;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_center != value)
            {
                _center = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    public int RadiusX
    {
        get
        {
            return _radiusX;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_radiusX != value)
            {
                _radiusX = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    public int RadiusY
    {
        get
        {
            return _radiusY;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_radiusY != value)
            {
                _radiusY = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;


    public void OnUpdate(Point center, int radiusX, int radiusY)
    {
        Center = center;
        RadiusX = radiusX;
        RadiusY = radiusY;
    }


    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

when you receive new values, call OnUpdate on your view model, it will set new values, raise PropertyChanged event, and your view will update.

3) code behind:

```
myImage.DataContext = new ImageViewModel { Center = new Point(320,480), RadiusX = 120, RadiusY = 120 }
```

4) XAML:

```
<Image x:Name="myImage" Source="/someImage.png">
    <Image.Clip>
        <EllipseGeometry Center="{Binding Point}" RadiusX="{Binding RadiusX}" RadiusY="{Binding RadiusY}" />
    </Image.Clip>
</Image>
```

Comment: One more query, If my image is of 640 width & 920 height. Then How to determine Center and Radius X/Y on EllipseGeometry ?

Comment: @prdp89 when you get new height and with just call OnUpdate with the following values: OnUpdate(new Point(width / 2, height / 2), height / 8, height / 8).